# How to query for "Contains" in Entity framework for long datatype without enumerating the result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have this very simple query:

```
 var val = context.aac_Account.Where(p => p.AcctNo.Equals(term)).Select(p=>new{

             value=p.AcctNo,
             label=p.AcctNo

        });
```

As you see above, the equals does not return any results. I could have used `.Contains` in case of string.

But what do I do for `long`? I cannot enumerate and filter the query since there are millions of records in it.

Is there any resolution for this?

Comment: What do you mean by `contains` in a `long` context? That 1024567 somehow contains 245?

Comment: You want to make your own 'Contains'? or i miss something?!

Comment: Yes SWeko, thats exactly what i want.I was using jquery ui autocomplete. so as the use key in the AccountNo, i need to retrieve ten records that matches it. I cannot do .Where(p=>p.AcctNo.ToString().Contains(term)), that would trigger a run time error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if thats, you'll have to create a store procedure or function in the database where you'll implement the contains functionality and the call it.

However you can try and implement it with fluent linq. Check this answer [HERE](http://forums.asp.net/t/1583023.aspx/1)